# Paypal Express Checkout for digital goods request for token getting killed

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

Ok so I am pretty new to paypal for digital goods. I have done some extensive reading but the paypal documentation seems to a bit overwhelming and information seems a bit spread out. Basically what I need to do is to sell credits on my site and I followed the instruction on integrating digital goods for express checkout. Here is my HTML form code

```
<form id = "paypalForm" style = "display:none;"  method="post">
<p>
<input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Pay with PayPal" />
<input type="hidden" name="METHOD"value="SetExpressCheckout" />
<input type="hidden" name="RETURNURL"value="http://ec2-54-244-155-132.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="CANCELURL"value="http://ec2-54-244-155-132.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"/>
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTACTION"value="sale"/>
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"value="USD"/>
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT"value="3"/>
<input type="hidden" name="L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0"value="Digital"/>
<input type="hidden" name="L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0"value="Deans Door Credits"/>
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"value="500"/>
<input type="hidden" name="L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0"value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0"value="100"/>
<input type="hidden" name="REQCONFIRMSHIPPING"value="0"/>
<input type="hidden" name="NOSHIPPING"value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="VERSION" value="65.1"> 

</p>
</form>
```

I then do an ajax submit but I dont seem to get a returned token. 
Any ideas, thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetExpressCheckout is only for getting a token.  Once you get that token you redirect the user to PayPal with that token appended to the end of the URL.  For digital goods, that would be something like this:  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?useraction=commit&token=EC-8MB725812K847260R

There the user signs in to PayPal to review and approve the payment and they are then sent back to the ReturnURL you specify in your SEC request.

At this point you can call GetExpressCheckoutDetails (optional) and you finalize everything by calling DoExpressCheckoutPayment.  Only after the DECP call is made will any payment actually be processed.

For more details refer to the [Express Checkout Integration Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_expresscheckout_integrationguide.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, I got it! They have alot of documentation for various things, so i was a little confused. But I figured it out!